# Fetching and parsing functionality location in MVC

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, rss

I need to load data from rss and display it in tableview. I decided to do it in some other class rather than in ViewController. So I created DataFetch class. The problem is that I use third party library to work with rss, and it works like this:

```
func fetchPodcastFeed() -> [RSSFeedItem]{
    let feedURL = NSURL(string: feedURLString)!
    var feedItems = [RSSFeedItem]()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), {
        // Run parsing in a background thread
        FeedParser(URL: feedURL)?.parse({ (result) in
            feedItems = (result.rssFeed?.items)!
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
              //reload table

            })
        })
    })   
    return feedItems
}
```

Of course when I call `fetchItems = dataFetcher.fetchPodcastFeed()` from ViewController I don't get any data. Should I use notifications and if so, how to pass fetched data to ViewController through them? Or is there better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume the `fetchPodcastFeed()` function is your code, right?
Then I'd suggest defining it with a callback like so:

```
func fetchPodcastFeed(onCompletion:(result:[RSSFeedItem]) -> Void) {
    // setup as you have it ...
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                // call the completion closure
                onCompletion(feedItems)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Then, wherever you're calling the method, do it like this:

```
fetchPodcastFeed({(result) in
    // reload your table with result, which is of type [RSSFeedItem]
})
```

Theoretically you could also simply pass the completion handler directly into the `parse` method you're calling on the `FeedParser` object, but since you are on a background thread it's probably wiser to first send it to the main thread again. Otherwise you'd have to put the reload table stuff in a `dispatch_async`call, it's nicer the way you started.